# SQL query result formatting

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

I am running an SQL Query and spooling the result into a .csv file. 
I am having a column called "Address" and it has data like this "1028 Rocky Road, APT 201".

1. My problem is, when data in spooled into .csv file, APT 201 is copied into the 
   field next to "Address".
2. Address filed is 240 length. I am trying to trim the white spaces but not able 
   to do it.

I am having a query something like this in UNIX script

```
SET COLSEP ,
SET HEADING ON
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET LINESIZE 32767
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET HEADSEP ON
SET PAGESIZE 1000

SPOOL filename.csv

SELECT first_name
      ,last_name
      ,address
      ,contact_num

FROM tablename

SPOOL OFF

EOF
```

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: Post the SQL you already wrote so people got something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use [column](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1007781) SQLPlus command to specify the length of your field:

```
column address format a240
```